# We would like to use onMouseOver event as opposed to OnClick event. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This example below is what we are trying to use to prevent user from submitting the form if any of the boxes is blank.

If any of the input textboxes is blank, an input textbox has a red rectangle around it.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    .error {
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}

.valid {
    border: 2px solid #0ff;
}

form, input {
    margin: 10px;
}
#docs {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(){
            return false;
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <form id="myform">

    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

We would like to use onMouseOver event as opposed to an onClick event.

This way, if a box is blank, the input textbox turns into red rectangle without having to click the Submit Query first.

Any ideas what I need to change to make this work as an onMouseOver event?

Comment: Note that you don't get "mouseover" events on touch screen devices.

Comment: This is not a task for jQuery, or even JavaScript. `<input type="text" name="field1" required />` The browser will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a mouseenter handler for the submit button

```
$('#myform input[type="submit"]').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#myform').valid()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q8Mpv/)

Comment: great!

Thank you sir for the prompt response.